# Computing ECDH (secp256k1) shared secret gives wrong result

Tags: swift, encryption, diffie-hellman, ecdh

I am trying to compute ECDH (**secp256k1**) shared secret based on private key "5785cb919db4984453826032a411248184536c632096c647f72db4e66a8bd091" and public key "0425a4ef791d8d855077c4d5dd6ca87cbda2f3296939a350e4ea57b3f0235fe1ba4d02cb29f6391675e866944065f9905a30a3e472c45c7ad7afa06143d87efa13"

I use [secp256k1](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/secp256k1) with swift.

```
    let myPrKeyBytes: [UInt8] = [87, 133, 203, 145, 157, 180, 152, 68,
                                 83, 130, 96, 50, 164, 17, 36, 129, 132,
                                 83, 108, 99, 32, 150, 198, 71, 247, 45,
                                 180, 230, 106, 139 ,208, 145]

    let myPubKeyBytes: [UInt8] = [4, 37, 164, 239, 121, 29, 141, 133,
                                  80, 119, 196, 213, 221, 108, 168, 124,
                                  189, 162, 243, 41, 105, 57, 163, 80,
                                  228, 234, 87, 179, 240, 35, 95, 225,
                                  186, 77, 2, 203, 41, 246, 57, 22, 117,
                                  232, 102, 148, 64, 101, 249, 144, 90,
                                  48, 163, 228, 114, 196, 92, 122, 215,
                                  175, 160, 97, 67, 216, 126, 250, 19]

    let ctx = secp256k1_context_create(UInt32(SECP256K1_CONTEXT_SIGN))

    var publicKeyParsed = secp256k1_pubkey()

    let publicKeyParseStatus = secp256k1_ec_pubkey_parse(
        ctx!,
        &publicKeyParsed,
        myPubKeyBytes,
        myPubKeyBytes.count
    )

    guard publicKeyParseStatus == 1 else {

        fatalError("Couldn't parse the public key")
    }


    let sharedSecretLength = 32
    let sharedSecret = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>
        .allocate(capacity: sharedSecretLength)

    let sharedSecretComputeStatus = secp256k1_ecdh(
        ctx!,
        sharedSecret,
        &publicKeyParsed,
        myPrKeyBytes
    )

    guard sharedSecretComputeStatus == 1 else {

        fatalError("Couldn't compute shared secret")
    }

    var sharedSecretBytes: [UInt8] = []
    for i in 0..<sharedSecretLength {

        sharedSecretBytes.append(sharedSecret[i])
    }

    let sharedSecretStr = sharedSecretBytes
        .map { String(format: "%02x", $0) }
        .joined()

    print("Shared secret: \(sharedSecretStr)")
    // Shared secret: 4d6f4351d68351c419408621efddfcfcc0bc10270669af822093fcf22c9ca26c
```

I've got "4d6f4351d68351c419408621efddfcfcc0bc10270669af822093fcf22c9ca26c" shared secret, but correct secret should be "ccf231a0ce74e92d9a94265ab27aa4616a3683af5df5aa65f4a011ad83673b49"

Comment: From which language is this `let` keyword?

Comment: It is Swift language

Comment: You can get inspiration from this pure Swift EC library: https://github.com/Sajjon/EllipticCurveKit

Comment: I don't get it. Why do you think that should be the answer, and why are you using the public key of what seems to be *your* key pair, rather than the public key of the other party?

Comment: I've computed shared secret using [elliptic](https://github.com/indutny/elliptic) in JS and code example from [here](https://asecuritysite.com/encryption/ecdh2) in Python. Both give same result ** ccf231a0ce74e92d9a94265ab27aa4616a3683af5df5aa65f4a011ad83673b49**

Comment: @Sajjon hello! your library is really great, but I can't understand how initiate `Message` from my custom `String`- what should be a `Hasher`? Can you please-please-please add this lines at `Readme.md`?

Comment: @nastassia will do tomorrow, ping me this weekend if I forget

Comment: @Sajjon Thanks for answering! I'm stuck with signing/verifying with one of the secp256k1-for-Swift wrappers, and hope your lib finally solve my issue :)

Comment: @nastassia  you know you should only be signing *hashed*. Hashing data makes sure that the message always have the same length. So if you wanna sign "Hello World", you hash it first. Let's say that hash results in the hex string `"D2A1...F21B"`  having length 64 characters. Using my lib you can either use Message(hashedHex: `"D2A1...F21B"`, hashedBy: DefaultHasher.sha256) or Message(). But I've updated the README with some info: https://github.com/Sajjon/EllipticCurveKit/blob/master/README.md#message